# Does $x^n$ belong to linear span$\{q(x)=\int_{0}^{x} p(t)dt,\ \ r(x)=\frac{d}{dx} p(x)\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $p(x)=a_{0}+a_{1}x+...+a_{n}x^{n}$ be a non-constant polynomial of degree $n \geq 1$. Consider the polynomial $q(x)=\int_{0}^{x} p(t)dt,\ \ r(x)=\frac{d}{dx} p(x).$ Let $V$ denote the real vector space of all polynomials in $x$. Then which of the following is true?
>
> 1) $q$ and $r$ are linearly independent in $V$
>
> 2) $q$ and $r$ are linearly dependent in $V$
>
> 3) $x^n$ belongs to the linear span of $q$ and $r$
>
> 4) $x^{n+1}$ belongs to the linear span of $q$ and $r$.

option 1) is true as $q$ and $r$ are linearly independent.

option 3) is true as for $p(x)=x^{n-1}$,  $x^n= n• q(x)+ 0•r(x)$.

option 4) is true as for $p(x)=x^{n}$,  $x^{n+1}= (n+1)• q(x)+ 0•r(x)$.

But the answer key says only 1) is true. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: The question is a little vague. Is $a_n \neq 0$?

Comment: nothing is said about $a_{i}$'s

Comment: Unless you know the $a_k$ you cannot know that 3), 4) are true.

Comment: Sorry, I should read more carefully. Since $\partial p = n$ we know that $a_n \neq 0 $.

Comment: Since $\partial q = n+1, \partial r = n-1$, any element in their linear span must have degree $n-1$ or $n+1$, hence 3) cannot be true. 4) can only be true if $p(x) = a_n x^n$.