# Is $x^{n+1}$ belong to the linear span of $q$ and $r$?

Tags: linear-algebra

some confusion in my  mind about this question [Does $x^n$ belong to linear span$\{q(x)=\int_{0}^{x} p(t)dt,\ \ r(x)=\frac{d}{dx} p(x)\}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286876/does-xn-belong-to-linear-span-qx-int-0x-ptdt-rx-fracddx)

> let $p(x) = a_0  +a_1 (x) + ........ + a_n x^n  $ be  non constant polynomial of degree  $n \ge 1. $ Consider the polynomial $ q(x) =   \int_{0}^{x} p(t)dt , r(x) = \frac{d}{dx} p(x)$.let $V$ denotes the real vector space  of all polynomial in $x$. which  of the  following are true ?
>
> $1.$ $q$ and $r$ are linesarly  independent in $ V$
>
> $2.$ $q$ and $r$ are linearly depenedent in $V$
>
> $3.$$x^n$ belong to the linear span of $q$ and $r$
>
> $4.$ $x^{n+1}$ belong to the linear span of $q$ and $r$

My attempt : option $1$ is true  , Suppose $r(x) +q(x) =a_1+ a_2(x) \dots+ na_nx^{n-1} +  b_ox+ b_1(x^2)/2 \dots+ nb_nx^{n+1}/n =0$ (that is, the constant zero function); this is a polynomial that has infinitely many roots, so it's the zero polynomial, which means $a_1=\dots=a_n= b_0 =b_1= \dots =b_n=0$. so both $q$ and $r$ are linearly independent

option $2$  is  false from option $1$

both Option  $3$  and $4 $ are  false because $ \text{max degree} (q(x)) = x^{n+1}$ which is not  belong in $ r$

Is its  true  ?

Comment: I don't get the explanation for option $1$ at all : I don't see even the expressions for $q$ and  $r$ in your explanation.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг i have edits its

Comment: There's an issue : why are you setting $r(x) = 0$? You are suppose to check if $q$ and $r$ are linearly dependent :  that is, are there constants $c,d$ such that $cq + dr = 0$. What you've shown is that $r = 0$ is not possible : that does not rule out all $c,d$, does it?

Comment: okss   ya  u are right @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг actually  i misread the option im thinking only about $r(x)$

Comment: No issue about the misread : I think you are right about option $3$ and $4$. The following simple result is key here : two non-zero polynomials of different degree are linearly independent. Prove this and use it here.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг i have edit once again see its

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question 1, I think you could explain it better, though I suspect that you do know why it's true. Essentially, $q$ and $r$ have different degrees. If they were linearly dependent, then either one would be the $0$ polynomial, or they would have the same degree (since one would have to be a non-zero multiple of the other). Since $r$ is the lower degree polynomial, it would have to be $0$, contradicting $\operatorname{degree} p \ge 1$.

Option $3$ is false for similar reasons. If you take a linear combination $aq + br$ of $q$ and $r$, then $a \neq 0$ produces an $x^{n+1}$ term, which no multiple of $r$ could cancel. So, we would have to have $a = 0$. But this would suggest that $x^n = br(x)$, which is impossible, since $r$ has degree $n - 1$.

Option $4$ might possibly be true, for example if $p(x) = x^n$. Then,
$$x^{n+1} = (n+1)q(x) + 0r(x).$$
On the other hand, it could be false too, e.g. if $p(x) = x^n + 1$.